# C# Console application not showing console output when starting from different application

Tags: c#

I am using a windows application to start a console application for command line parameters configuration.

When I am sending the command line parameters through debug mode, the application is working perfect, and all Console.WriteLine is printing to console, but when am starting the process from windows application of that console application it is not showing console output

the way, am starting the process is

```
           ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            procStartInfo.FileName = EXEName;
            procStartInfo.Arguments = FilePath;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                process.Start();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to `false`;

Comment: I've just tried and my solution is working perfectly with your code if I modified the `RedirectStandardOutput` option.

Comment: what is in your `EXEName` and `FilePath` variables?